# Input box goes to next line

Tags: html

Hi guys so I have an input box that goes to next line on text-input.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because a link is just like any other text in your paragraph, just that it might have different formatting and causes a page change when clicked. Like any other text, word wrapping in the browser know that it can break a line on the space. If you don't want it to break there, change it to a non-breaking space: `Contact&nbsp;Us`

Comment: @SeZThis If that fixed it, would you mind accepting my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this CSS to prevent line breaks:

```
a { display: inline-block; }
```